# how to deploy the nodejs expressjs for api, reactjs for frontend and angular for admin

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, express, vps

How can we deploy the nodejs with SSL certificates,
I have expressjs for API, reactjs for front-end and angular for backend, 
i need a path like - https://www.domainname.com - for frontend https://www.domainname.com/admin for admin and expressjs api run on background with https. like https://www.domainname.com/api/register

I have merge the expressjs and reactjs into one project and it works fine on local machine but how i can run the admin like - http://localhost/admin (it works with port like http://localhost:4200) but i want with admin. Please let me how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could host your admin application separately and use a CDN like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com) to serve it as a subdomain (admin.domainname.com). Cloudflare comes with free SSL.